# UITableView vs UICollectionView vs UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

When should I use which, and what are the disadvantages or disadvantages of each? I'm mainly confused with scrollview vs collectionview, I know tableview is limited to one column (I heard it gets messy when more than one column), but scrollview difference with collectionview seem the same to me.

Comment: Hint: UICollectionView is a UIScrollView (and so is UITableView).

Comment: @rmaddy I know that, but I don't get when to use one over the other. Can't collectionview do everything scrollview can but just better? Why even use scrollview ever if that's the case

Comment: Do you have any scenes what you expect？

Comment: Sometimes all you need is a hammer. In engineering in general, always use the right tool for the job. If you have a very static (non-dynamic) screen with just a few view objects, for example, why would you ever not just use a scroll view? Why would this screen require a data source? If the screen is more dynamic and all it needs is a single column of cells, why would you ever not just use a table view? And if the screen calls for more complexity, consider a collection view. As programmers, we should always strive for efficiency whether it's code simplicity, memory usage, or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both CollectionView & TableView are basically subclasses of UIScrollView.But as compared to UIScrollView here you are provided with proper methods to provide your dataSource & delegates to handle operations user performs on data. Along with this you are provided predefined layout classes. 
Now to choose between them completely depends on your UI Requirements. Suppose you want to display just a list of items with a simple UI go with TableView.If you want a custom Layout like a grid or like the one you see in Apple's photo's app CollectionView is the choice.
if you have a complex UI & you have no idea about Custom CollectionView layout classes go with scrollView.

Comment: Ty! Do you think you could help explain what they used (out of the 3 ) in here? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SYGqhIJ4dQ What is the main view, probably collectionviews for the sideway scrolling views right?

Comment: They could have used a ScrollView here or may be a tableview with multiple custom cells.Like one cell for the item  info. For the main view it might contain one cell for the item info . The special offer cell which basically contains a collectionView indide it.One cell for order summary , one for promotion and so on. TabvleView 's are easier to manage as compared to a ScrollView.

Comment: That's possible with tableview? Even just having one cell = to just one viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

Consider UITableView and UICollectionView first and if you cannot achieve the effect you want with them, try UIScrollView then. UIScrollView is more basic class. UITableView and UICollectionView have more delegate method for us.
If you want a list,UITableView would be better. And if you want a multicolumn,use UICollectionView.